# Paramiko raises 'AuthenticationException' sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

This is one of those rare cases that it's nearly impossible to reproduce, but I've seen it happen 4 times out of 20.

Here's my open_session method:

```
def open_session:
    self.session = paramiko.SSHClient()
    self.host = host
    self.username = username
    self.password = password

    self.session.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        self.session.connect(self.host, username=self.username, port=port, password=self.password, timeout=self.connect_timeout)
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.BadHostKeyException:
        message = "host key could not be verified"
        self.sys_conf.logger.warning(message)
        raise BadCredentials(message)
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
        message = "authentication failed."
        self.sys_conf.logger.warning(message)
        raise BadCredentials(message)
    except (paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException, socket.error) as e:
        message = "could not establish connection, an error occurred: {}".format(e)
        self.sys_conf.logger.warning(message)
        raise ConnectionFail(message)
    except socket.timeout:
        message = "could not establish connection, time's out!"
        self.sys_conf.logger.warning(message)
        raise ConnectionFail(message)
```

Any particular reason why Paramiko does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, it turns out that it's an issue with the machine itself. The code mentioned in my initial question is good as is and worked 300 times in a row without fail on another, more stable machine.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
self.session = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.host = host
self.username = username
self.password = password
self.session.load_system_host_keys() # u missed this
self.session.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
```

load_system_host_keys(filename=None)
Load host keys from a system (read-only) file. Host keys read with this method will not be saved back by save_host_keys.
[poaramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.load_system_host_keys)

Comment: I didn't entirely understand what it does, could you please explain? When this method isn't run, are the host keys loaded from the user’s local “known hosts” file? Or are the host keys not loaded at all? If it's the latter, then why does authentication pass most of the time?

Comment: read:
http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.load_system_host_keys

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626347/when-and-why-to-use-load-host-keys-and-load-system-host-keys

Comment: Both your answer and the other SO answer were pretty much copy-paste from the Paramiko documentation. Which I read and didn't understand, this is why I asked for further explanation..

Comment: Testing right now. As I said, it fails _some_ of the time, so it might take a while until it fails. From what I understood, there is no "known hosts" file on windows machines (the machine I'm running the script from is a Windows machine), so.. Are host keys not loaded at all? If so, how does authentication pass most of the time but fails sometimes?

Comment: Update: This answer did not fix my issue.